# How do you append data to an XHR request beforeSend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a form that submits with remote=true using Rails UJS.

In the beforeSend event I want to append data. I'm trying with the following:

```
onNewListItemFormBeforeSend : function(event, xhr, settings) {

  settings.data += { 'list_item[title]' : input_val,
    'list_item[position]' : 0,
    'list_items[open_positions]' : 'stuff',
   'list_items[done_positions]' : 'stuff' )
  };

}
```

But this is adding an object when I log out settings.data ... What is the right way to append these items to settings.data?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I also tried just doing:

```
settings.data = { 'number' : 'XXXXXX' }
```

But that didn't work. In the logs I see:

```
 Started POST "/lists/9/list_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-24 11:55:39 -0700
     Processing by ListItemsController#create as JSON
     Parameters: {"object Object"=>nil, "list_id"=>"9"}
```

Why the object object nil?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer version of `jquery_ujs` you should be able to use the `data-params` (if you're able to do it at this point).  Otherwise, you can bind to `ajax:before` and modify the data at that point. I'd learn towards `data-params` myself.

Here's a bit more detail to the same problem:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.data["list_item"] = { 'title' : input_val,
    'position' : 0,
    'open_positions' : 'stuff',
    'done_positions' : 'stuff'
};
```

try something like this. You can create the "list_item" property and set it dynamically in js like this.

Comment: Thanks but that's not working... the items aren't being appended when I log settings.data